# Convert a list of strings containing list-of-integers into an array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series that is a list of lists that contain integers that I am attempting to turn into an array. This is a small snip-it of the list I am trying to convert into an array.

```
['[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]',

'[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]',

'[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]',

'[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]',

'[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]']
```

I've tried to replace the quotes with .replace, but that hasn't worked out.

```
sequence = [i.replace(" '' ", ' ') for i in sequence]
```

Comment: So you have a list of strings which each represent a list of integers?

Comment: Yes! And I want to convert that list of integers into an array.

Comment: You may use `ast.literal_eval()` to turn your strings into Python lists...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to change the string to list of lists of ints

```
sequence = [literal_eval(i) for i in sequence]

# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

You can change it to `numpy` array

```
import numpy as np

array = np.asarray(sequence)
print(array)
```

output

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]]
```

Or to 1d `pandas` array

```
import pandas as pd

array = pd.array([item for items in sequence for item in items])
print(array)
```

outout

```
<IntegerArray>
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
Length: 50, dtype: Int64
```